# Render an user interface in memory

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

let's say I have hwnd handle and would like to add some GUI controls in memory. I also receive all user input via events. 
So, is it possible to use wxwidgets to add a user interface to an image which will be drawn onto the a Window ( using such hwnd handle ). If so, does wxwidget have some facilities to keep track of state of the GUI?

I'm new to wxwidgets and so please excuse my general questions.

Many thanks,
Christian

Answer (score 1):

The only way to add GUI controls to an image, is to draw them yourself. The only way to do that, would be to create an image GUI element, and position the other GUI elements relative to the image element. However, this will not do double-buffering of the UI like you want to do, it doesn't actually draw the UI elements in the image, just places them on top of the image.